# Equivalent of “ScreenUpdating” in Google Apps Script (equivalent VBA-GAS )

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, refresh, spreadsheet, updating

I'm looking for the equivalent VBA-GAS of:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I'm running a very long macro in one of my Google Spreadsheets and it takes at least 30 seconds to finish it every time. It would be helpful if the macro didn't refresh the screen after every line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isnt. However you should batch all setValues into range writes (ideally a single range write) which will help here.
Only call SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the very end.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? If I'm reading and updating a single column, should I get that column as a range and read an update the range? do I use myrange.getRange(1, 2).setValue('Title'); rather than sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue('Title'); or am I being dense?

Comment: This is a bit of an oversight on Google's part IMHO.  Batching writes to cells works for a single sheet, but it doesn't work for adding, deleting or re-ordering sheets within a spreadsheet.  The resulting mess as the animations try to keep up is not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a second sheet called 'Start' which just had A1='Please wait...'. The sheet I display all my data on is called 'Report'

Then used:

```
//Hide Report sheet
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Start").showSheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Report");
sheet.hideSheet();

//Code to update sheet here
sheet.appendRow('Blah','Blah','Blah');

//Show Report sheet
sheet.showSheet();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().setActiveSheet(sheet);
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Start").hideSheet();
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach doesn't increase overall macro speed =(

Answer (score 1):

While I understand that the below does not necessarily speed up the macro, it makes for a better UX and is important to note. 
For many function calls and updates, VBA first requires that we "unhide" the respective sheet:

```
' Unhide the sheet, write to it, hide it '
Dim lastrow As Long

Sheets("Report").Visible = True
Sheets("Report").Select

' Append a Row '
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A").Value = "Blah"

Sheets("Report").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
```

The same is not required for many of the Google Apps Script Classes:

```
// Hide the sheet, write to it, show it
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Report').hideSheet();
sheet.appendRow(['Blah']);
sheet.showSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this is by bypassing every instance of "setActiveSheet" or "activate."

For example:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('B4').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

can be shortened to:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet2!B4'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

and can be run from any sheet on the document without changing the selected sheet or cell.

There may be a reason for Google to automatically add this redundancy, but this does appear to work in every case I've used it in.

Answer (score 0):

If your script involves looping through some range and reading and/or writing values, it will always be slow as every read/write is a separate API call.

Instead of looping through 10 rows and reading a cell value like in excel VBA, you should specify the range with getRange() and get all values by one call, which can be done with getValues(). It returns a 2d array with values from specified range.

You can do all operations you need on that data and you can return values with setValues()