# Prevent Screen-updating in Google Sheet Macro

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a long macro that is running in my Google Sheets. It take about 2 minutes to finish. It continually loads each of the 24 tabs as it processes the macro. I know this is taking time and would prefer it not to show the screen updating. I have tried "SpreadsheetApp.ScreenUpdating = False" and "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" with no success. How do I stop the screen from updating with the macro? Any help with this would be amazing! Thanks!

I tried

SpreadsheetApp.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

with no success.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749869/equivalent-of-screenupdating-in-google-apps-script-equivalent-vba-gas

Comment: In other words, please supply the code for the macro